# Running code under another user in custom timer job

Tags: timer-jobs

My OWSTIMER.EXE process is running under network service.

I have a certain timer job that should perform the following actions:

1. Add taxonomy terms to a certain term store
2. Add items to a certain sharepoint list, located in a certain sharepoint site.

While this alone isn't rocket science, the timer job runs under the same principal as the OWSTimer.exe process, so in other words network service.

Obviously I don't want the network service account to have permissions to manage a taxonomy term store, neither SharePoint lists, so I had already setup an account to do this.

How can I run blocks of code in my timer job under this account I created which should have access to the term store and sharepoint lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dare I ask why you have the timer service running under the Network service account? 
Seems to me you are tackling the problem the wrong way. 
Best practice would be to run the timer service under a (least privileged) service account.

Comment: I think this is the way to tackle the problem. Would have been nice if timer jobs could be configured to run under certain identities, rather than the one size fits all timer service running everything. But this will suffice for now.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of User Impersonation to have blocks of code run as another user.

Good example here: http://blackninjasoftware.com/2009/04/09/how-to-programmatically-impersonate-users-in-sharepoint/